# Show that: If $A \in \Bbb{R}^{n×n}$ a diagonal matrix [...]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $A \in \Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the diagonal matrix 
$$A = \operatorname{diag}(λ_1,\dots,λ_n)$$
with real positive diagonal elements, and with the standard scalar product $\langle ·,·\rangle$ is 
$$\langle x, y \rangle' := \langle Ax,y \rangle$$ 
also a scalar product.

Does this (in case $ n = 2 $) also apply to the matrix 
$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2&1 \\ 1&2 \end{pmatrix}$?

I hope I translated this all correctly :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the question.

$\langle Ax,y\rangle=\lambda_1x_1y_1+\lambda_2x_2y_2+\cdots+\lambda_1 x_n y_n$

However with the matrix you have defined

$\langle Ax,y\rangle=(2x_1+x_2)y_1+(x_1+2x_2)y_2$.

So they are not the same. Is this what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

A positive definite matrix can be written in the form of $A=LL^T$.

Hence, we have

$$\langle Ax, y \rangle=x^TA^Ty=x^TLL^Ty = \langle L^Tx, L^Ty\rangle$$